# Error when using Dapper and Devart driver together to connect to Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, orm, dapper, devart

I am trying to do a simple select from a Oracle table with Dapper using the Devart driver

```
using (var sqlConnection = new Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection(cs))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    var sql = @"SELECT ""AnalasisId"" = @AnalasisId, ""Name"" = @Name, ""Description"" = @Description, ""AnalasisGroupId"" = @AnalasisGroupId FROM ""Analasis"";";
    var analasis = sqlConnection.Query<Analasis>(sql);
}
```

But I get

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

If I run

```
SELECT "AnalasisId" = @AnalasisId, "Name" = @Name, "Description" = @Description, "GroupId" = @GroupId FROM "Analasis";
```

In Oracle SQL Dev then I get the same error, so I guess my mapping is wrong, but then how am I supposed to do the mapping with dapper to my C# class ?

Is there a better driver than devart suited for this?

Comment: Are you trying to do a filter? or are you trying to alias the columns? that sql just ... isn't sql!

Comment: Alias the columns, I just looked at the official github https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net "Example usage:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL syntax does not look like Oracle. Try this one:

```
var sql = @"SELECT AnalasisId, Name, Description FROM Analasis";
```

Comment: What if the DB column name and the object property have different names, how do I map it then?

Comment: `SELECT AnalasisId AS ANALYZE_ID,`